# Primefaces Slider Component Syntax JavaScript Error in IE

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces 2.2.1 and I'm experiencing an issue with the p:slider component. I get a Syntax error on the line below (see source).  Thats all IE gives me.  Any ideas?

xhtml:

```
<h:form id="dreamEditFrm">
   <h:inputHidden id="cost" value="#{dreamModifyBean.selectedDream.cost}" />
   <p:slider for="cost" minValue="1" maxValue="5"/>
</h:form>
```

source:

```
  <input id="dreamEditFrm:costTxt" type="text" name="dreamEditFrm:costTxt" />
         <div id="dreamEditFrm:j_idt149"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript">widget_dreamEditFrm_j_idt149 = new PrimeFaces.widget.Slider('dreamEditFrm:j_idt149', {value:,input:'dreamEditFrm:costTxt',min:1,max:5,animate:true,step:1,orientation:'horizontal'});       </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part of the html output:

```
 {value:,
```

It seems that the value attribute can't get connected to the slider. Maybe your el expression does not resolve correctly (although there should be other error messages).

Is *cost* displayed if you use `h:inputText` or `h:outputText`?

Did you try other browsers?